# Responsive website breaks in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My website works perfectly till IE9, all hell breaks lose at IE8.
What my header looks like:

```
<head>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
<title></title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<meta content="en" http-equiv="content-language" name="language"/>
<system-page-meta-keywords/>
<system-page-meta-description/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
</head>
```

We also tried adding this to our htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch MSIE ie
        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

How do I force old IE8 browsers to render as latest IE versions? What am I doing wrong here? Please help, we are few hours shy of launching!

Comment: I am going to guess that you used media queries to make the site responsive right? I've got bad news for you, media queries are not supported in ie8.

Comment: A lot of things arent supported in IE8....

Comment: You can't get IE8 to render the way IE9 does, things aren't forward-compatible like that. You'll have to target IE8 specifically to combat things.

Comment: is there a way of looking at a website's markup and tell how they are combating IE8? I am really curious about this website: www.uchicago.edu

Answer (score 2):

You can't usually make old versions of software behave like new ones. In this case, IE8 doesn't support media queries, so you need to use a polyfill, such as [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond).